# Hierarchy of modules in guice

Tags: guice

I'd like to run a unit test where a constant is slightly different than in the standard version. That is, in my default module, the following is

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("number of players")).to(4);
```

but in testing, I'd like to try this line instead:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("number of players")).to(2);
```

Id like to achieve that without copying all of the rest of the module. What I really want is a "default" module that is "below" a more specialized module, such that in case of conflict, the specialized module wins (instead of throwing an exception, which is what guice does).

In essence, my question is: how does anybody arrange for more than one module without lots of code duplication?

**Update**: I've realized that the solution is really to use a factory, rather than a constant in THIS use case. I'd still be interested to learn if there's something like hierarchies of modules in general, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically when using Guice properly, you shouldn't need to use Guice at all in tests (particularly unit tests... integration and end-to-end tests, yes). Anyway:

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do or what the issue is exactly but... you realize that when creating an `Injector` you can provide any number of `Module`s to it, right? That's a key part of using Guice. Make the modules as course or fine-grained as you want. You could have a `NumberOfPlayersModule` that only has that one binding, and then use a different module with a different binding instead sometimes (like for your test). You could also make a module that takes a constructor argument and create the module as `new NumberOfPlayersModule(4)` or `new NumberOfPlayersModule(2)` as you like.

There's also another feature of Guice that lets you override bindings in one or more modules with bindings from one or more other modules. That works like this:

```
// FooModule is your module that contains the "number of players" binding and
// some others

Module override = Modules.override(new FooModule())
   .with(new AbstractModule() {
      protected void configure() {
         bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("number of players")).to(2);
      }
   });
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(override);
// The int @Named("number of players") for the injector is 2
```

As you can see, there are really quite a lot of ways to make configuring your application different ways easy.

Comment: Override! That's precisely what I wanted! Thank you!